# How to change all occurrences of variable name in Visual Studio Code for PHP?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have tried Ctrl + F12 but it does not really work. It does not select $this-> for some reasons. Does anyone here know, how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Karthikeyan the question belongs to VS Code

Answer (score 4):

Currently, Visual Studio Code's support for PHP is limited (see [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/php)), and I was unable to locate a PHP language service extension for Visual Studio Code ([you're welcome to look, too](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=php&target=VSCode&sortBy=Relevance)).

Visual Studio Code currently only comes bundled with language services for JavaScript and TypeScript.

According to [Visual Studio Code's documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_editing-smart), a language service is defined as follows:

> Language services provide the code understanding necessary for features like IntelliSense (suggestions) and smart code navigation (Go to Definition, **Find All References, Rename Symbol**).

Comment: I really like the background on this answer, but it doesn't quite feel like an answer. There is a similar question that might be useful for anyone that stumbles into this. It highlights more on rename binding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731353/rename-refactoring-for-php-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 4):

This question is a bit old but, for anyone who stumbled upon here,

You could use **PHP Refactor Tool** extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=st-pham.php-refactor-tool

note that this extension dependent on PHP intelephense: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client

Comment: OMG thank you so much! This extension is perfect! Exactly what I was looking for (and boy was I looking long and hard). The only thing I was missing from PHPStorm. Now I can finally switch to VSCode for non-work related projects (at least), to go easy with the resource consumption on my vintage MacBook.

I don't even care if this comment gets reported/deleted for being pointless, I'm just so happy and grateful I finally found this tool that I had to thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the regular search and replace <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+H</kbd>. VS Code provides preview for all planned replacements so it is done not that bad as you would expect.

Comment: It is similar to `ctrl+F` which is for all occurrences `ctrl+shift+F` in vscode.